# Using getters and setters with ArrayLists in java

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, getter-setter

I'm trying to read a csv and storing the records in an ArrayList.
Since I know the no. of records in the csv file I'm specifying the size i.e. 600 when creating the object.
I want the program to be able to read files of unknown no. of records.
How do I make it dynamic.

Here's the working code for the file with 600 records.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;


public class BankRecords extends Client{
//Create objects for processing data
//private static int count;
static BankRecords[] obj=new BankRecords[600];
static List<List<String>> array = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
@Override
void readData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String line=" ";
    //int i=0;

    //try with resources statement
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bank-Detail.csv"))){

        while((line=br.readLine()) != null) //read from file
        {   
            array.add(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));
            //check data
            //count++;
            //System.out.println(array.get(i++));
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    processData();
}
@Override
void processData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int idx=0;
    for(List<String> bankData: array)
    {

        obj[idx]= new BankRecords();
        obj[idx].setId(bankData.get(0));
        obj[idx].setAge(Integer.parseInt(bankData.get(1)));
        obj[idx].setSex(bankData.get(2));
        obj[idx].setRegion(bankData.get(3));
        obj[idx].setIncome(Double.parseDouble(bankData.get(4)));
        obj[idx].setMarried(bankData.get(5));
        obj[idx].setChild(Integer.parseInt(bankData.get(6)));
        obj[idx].setCar(bankData.get(7));
        obj[idx].setSact(bankData.get(8));
        obj[idx].setCact(bankData.get(9));
        obj[idx].setMort(bankData.get(10));
        obj[idx].setPep(bankData.get(11));


        idx++;

        //System.out.println(obj[idx].getId());
        }

    printData();
}





@Override
void printData() {

    //Printing First 25 ID, age, sex, region, income and mortgage
    System.out.println("ID\t\tAGE\t\tSEX\t\tREGION\t\tINCOME\t\tMORTGAGE\n");
    for(int i=0;i<25;i++){

        String s=String.format("%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%-10s\t%8.2f\t%2s", obj[i].getId(),obj[i].getAge(),obj[i].getSex(),obj[i].getRegion(),obj[i].getIncome(),obj[i].getMort());
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}




public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}




public int getAge() {
    return age;
}




public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}




public String getSex() {
    return sex;
}




public void setSex(String sex) {
    this.sex = sex;
}




public String getRegion() {
    return region;
}




public void setRegion(String region) {
    this.region = region;
}




public double getIncome() {
    return income;
}




public void setIncome(double income) {
    this.income = income;
}




public String isMarried() {
    return married;
}




public void setMarried(String married) {
    this.married = married;
}




public int getChild() {
    return child;
}




public void setChild(int child) {
    this.child = child;
}




public String getCar() {
    return car;
}




public void setCar(String car) {
    this.car = car;
}




public String getSact() {
    return sact;
}




public void setSact(String sact) {
    this.sact = sact;
}




public String getCact() {
    return cact;
}




public void setCact(String cact) {
    this.cact = cact;
}




public String getMort() {
    return mort;
}




public void setMort(String mort) {
    this.mort = mort;
}




public String getPep() {
    return pep;
}




public void setPep(String pep) {
    this.pep = pep;
}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BankRecords bnk= new BankRecords();
    bnk.readData();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) can the elements dynamically, so it is not required to know the size in advance.

However, for the `BankRecords` array, do not initialize it with 600 initially. Instead do something like this:

```
static BankRecords[] obj = null;
static List<List<String>> array = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
void processData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    obj=new BankRecords[array.size()];
    // TODO do your work here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to know the number of records beforehand in order to use an `ArrayList`.  You can specify a default size in the constructor, however it is smart enough to expand itself if you add more records than this.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, but for some strange reasons you are using Lists in places where you already have an array; yet on the other side, you are using an array where a List would be a much better fit.

You can rework your code as follows:

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

HINT: those TODOs are generated by your IDE. The idea is that you **delete** them as soon as you have some real content instead. Keeping them means leaving **garbage** in your source code. Anything that doesn't add real value to your source code: **remove** it. Always. Immediately!

```
String line=" ";
List<Bankrecord> records = new ArrayList<>();
//int i=0; ... again: unused code --- remove that!
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bank-Detail.csv"))){
    while((line=br.readLine()) != null) //read from file
    {   
      String[] lineData = line.split(",");
      BankRecord recordForNewLine = buildRecordFrom(lineData);
      records.add(recordForNewLine);
    } ...
```

And then you could rework your *processData* into something like:

```
private BankRecord buildRecordFrom(String[] lineData) {
  BankRecord newRecord = new BankRecords();
  newRecord.setId(lineData[0];
  ...
  return newRecord;
}
```

And things that you should really consider changing, too:

- Building your bank records by simply assuming that column contains a valid ID, and the next column contains a valid xyz ... is a **bad** idea.
- Instead, you should be **validating** all your input: you should check that each array you gain from *split* has **exactly the expected length. And then have to validate that each value from that array has the expected "content"
- Then, from a modelling perspective: you have a ton of **setters** on your Bankrecord class. But that is simply wrong! In real life, when some "record" is created, then its essential properties (such as its ID) can't be changed after creation!
- Instead, you should make sure that such properties in your class can't be changed after the object has been created. The way to go here: [Builder pattern](https://blog.codecentric.de/2015/04/cascaded-builder-pattern-in-java/)!

Finally: my code above is meant as "inspiration point" to get you going. Dont blindly copy/paste it; there might be various typos in - just read it until you get what (and why) it is doing (what it is doing)!

Then: I hope you understand that **real** CSV parsing is much more complicated than splitting around "," (for example: strings in CSV data can contain ',' too; and then your simple split would rip up that string!)
If you are serious about parsing real-world-other-people CSV input, then you better look into using existing libraries to do this for you. Writing a **correct** CSV parser is **hard** work (and not very rewarding; since that means re-inventing a complicated wheel for no good reason)!